# Translate query from MSSQL to PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, case

This query update one column if UserName has only numbers.

```
UPDATE [dbo].[MyTable]
SET [MyColumn] = CAST(CASE 
            WHEN UserName LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
                THEN 0
            ELSE 1
            END AS BIT)
```

I need to retranslate it to postgreSql. It must be something like this

```
UPDATE "MySheme"."MyTable"
SET "MyColumn" = CAST(CASE 
            WHEN "UserName" LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
                THEN 0
            ELSE 1
            END AS BIT)
```

Comment: Unlike MSSQL PostgreSQL has a boolean data type, which you would normally use instead of a bit. You can then directly assign it true or false without any casting. If you do want to use a bit then cast like this ... `then 0::bit else 1::bit`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

```
update mytable
set mycolumn = (username !~ '\d')::int::bit
```

This produces a `bit` value of `1` if `username` does not contain any digit, else `0`.

Note that Postgres supports the `boolean` datatype, that would probably make more sense here. This would also simply the query:

```
update mytable
set mycolumn = (username !~ '\d')
```

Note that I did not quote the identifiers. Quoted identifiers usually add no value, and make queries unnecessarily lengthy - I would recommend avoiding them in your set up.